# force explicit interface implementation

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Imagine we have an interface `IFoo`:

```
interface IFoo {
    void DoSomething();
}
```

Now we have an implementing class which calls this method within its constructor:

```
class MyBase : IFoo {

    MyBase() { this.DoSomething(); }

    void DoSomething() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Finally we have a class that inherits `MyBase` but shell provide another implementaion of the interface `IFoo`. But when debugging I realise that constructor only accesses the implemetation on `MyBase` which I understand. Do get the right implementation of the interface I could explicitly call the interface-method from within the constructor using `((IFoo) this).DoSomething();`

```
class MyDerived : MyBase, IFoo {
    void DoSomething() { /* ... */ }
}
```

But how can I enforce that the method MUST be cast to that interface before using it? I know I can explicitly implement the interface within both classes, but who forces me to do so? So we finally come to something like: how can I force someone who inherits my class to explicitly implement my interface also?

EDIT: Another approach would be to make `DoSomething` virtual in `MyBase` and ommit the derived class from implementing `IFoo`. However I get R#-Warning on calling virtual member within constructor then.

Comment: Could you please show the code of the child class too? is it necessary to make MyBase concrete or it can be abstract?

Comment: Can't you make the method virtual?

Comment: `MyBase` is concrete class and cannot be abstract. @LasseV.Karlsen see my edit.

Comment: The warning that ReSharper gives you would be just as valid if you were to cast `this` to the interface and call the method, and that method is implemented in a descendant. If it's OK in one situation it should be OK in the other, but the warning says you shouldn't write code like that.

Comment: If you want to implement DoSomething on the child class, override the parent's behaviour, then you need to mark it as virtual. If not, you're creating a new method in the child class.

Comment: To be specific. There is nothing inherently wrong with calling a `virtual` method from the constructor of a base class. The problem comes when you override that method. The overriden method is defined in a type that has yet to have its constructor called, and thus it may not be safe to call that method, that's what ReSharper is warning you about. The same problem applies to explicitly calling the explicitly implemented method through the interface except that ReSharper doesn't detect that scenario.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Really? But R# won´t complain if I use the interface instead.

Comment: No, it won't, but that doesn't mean that is safe. If you write a virtual method that is safe to be called in a descendant type before the constructor of that type has executed, it will be safe to call an explicitly implemented method through an interface as well. If you write the virtual method such that it isn't safe to call it yet, calling such a method through the interface won't be safe either.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen OK, I see, thank you

Comment: You should document that the method will be called from the base constructor, to indicate that it has to either fail silently or run successfully, even if the constructor of the descendant type hasn't executed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do, mark the method in base class as virtual so it can be overriden in the child class. The child class doesn't need to explicitly implement the interface because it is inheriting the parent's behaviour.

```
interface IFoo {
    void DoSomething();
}

class MyBase : IFoo {

    MyBase() { this.DoSomething(); }

    **virtual** void DoSomething() { /* ... */ }
}

class MyDerived : MyBase {
    **override** void DoSomething() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: I also thought about this, see my edit. However R# printed a warning on that. Probably I can ignore it in my scenario.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Pardon my ignorance, but what is R#?

Comment: R# warnings are useful but R# is not a compiler. This code is safe and coded in the right way. You're changing the behaviour of a method in the child class and that's part of the OOP. You know that the implicit constructor of MyDerived class will call the constructor of MyBase (a base() method call is implicit as the first line of the constructor of MyDerived class) and that's it.

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein Thanks for pointing the point on OOP out.

Comment: The Resharper warnings are there for a reason. Calling virtual methods inside constructor is generally unsafe. It could be possible to call a parameter which is initialized (or injected via one of the child constructor) before the other inherited classes could initialize it. It's a bad design and one of the reasons it's displayed as a warning. Even if you know your implementation doesn't do that, if someone inherits that class he could still violate it, so the statement of **this code is safe and the right way** is just completely wrong